# Привязка блока к верху страницы

Tags: position, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте

Есть 2 блока, расположены вертикально.
По-умолчанию расположены один за другим. Типа:

```
  Блок 1  
  Блок 2
```

Как сделать чтобы при сколлинге страницы вниз(когда 1-й блок уже скрыт), 2-й блок(нижний) привязывался к верху страницы.

Спасибо.

Comment: В будущем можно будет использовать CSS: `position: sticky` ... Пока поддержа «[нулевая](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чистом css это сделать не получится. Это можно реализовать с помощью [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без jQuery. Но совсем без JS не получится.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById('B').style.position = scrolled > 150 ? 'fixed' : 'inherit';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.A {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EEE;
}

.B {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #66A;
}
```

```html
<div class='A'></div>
<div id='B' class='B'></div>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
```